# Syncing Kiwi using 'hard links' into Chrome's data folder

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, chromium, kiwi-browser

Kiwi Browser has no syncing option, while other Chromium browsers do
have.

### A workaround

The idea/hack is to:

1. install another browser (like Chrome Beta),
2. not use it,
3. and hard-wired Kiwi's data into the former's data folder.
4. *(existing Kiwi will trigger the other browser syncing activity)*

### The following experimental script,

is trying to hard-link Chrome's data to a different folder.

*Note that Kiwi Browser isn't involved yet at all.*

This is just a POC, to see how well a Chromium browser works with "hard links".

### Is it working? - No.

Chrome is able to open correctly.
But it saves nothing as expected.
Not Preferences, not History, not nothing.

```
# Source (Chrome's data),
# Target (the folder outside of Chrome):

S="./app_chrome/Default"

T="/data/data/shared/app_chrome/Default"

# Creation of hard links:

cd /data/data/com.android.chrome 

ln -f $T/History $S

ln -f $T/Bookmarks $S

ln -f $T/Preferences $S
```

*P.S.: with 'soft' (symbolic) link (instead of the above 'hard-links'), Chrome will not even be able to launch.*

Comment: Presumably you are rooted, to be able to create hardlinks? What directories actually exist once you've done all this?

Comment: @John Dallman   True, on rooted phone. How much folders are involved ? - Two: 1. 
/data/com.chrome/ app_chrome/default  - contains chrome original files.   2. ...com.kiwi/... - contains hard-links (instead of its original files), pointing to the former (chrome).